# Adding Span class when i'm using using Jquery "replace" function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think my problem is simple to resolve but i didn't find anything related to this. I just want to add a class id when i use JQuery replace.

Here i'm using this small script :

```
<script>
  $("body").html($("body").html().replace(" <strong>Mario</strong> game" , " <span class="class-id"><strong> Mario</strong> bros."));
  </script>
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: You can't nest `"` inside `"` so just switch to `'`: `" <span class='class-id'>..."` .  See the existing questions for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about

```
  $("body").replaceWith("<span class='red'><strong> Mario</strong> bros.");
```

Example here:
https://codepen.io/polinq/pen/yLKNggV?editors=1111